# Cant get JSON data with JQuery from Webapi to <table>, ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I've been stuck with this problem for some time now and I just can't get it to work. It does nothing at the moment and I dont know what I've done wrong.

JSON data:

```
{"$id":"1","content":"hej","fname":"Emanuel","subject":"hejsan"}
```

JQuery method:

```
    function get_latest_messages(id) {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:xxxxx/api/value/' + id, function (data) {
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                tr = $('#tableMessage');
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].fname + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].content + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + data[i].subject + "</td>");
                $('#tableMessage').append(tr);
            }
        });
```

HTML-Table-code:

```
  <table border="1" id="tableMessage">
<tr>
    <th>Från</th>
    <th>Ämne</th>       
    <th>Meddelande</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

ASP.net, Page_load code. id is declared in the method.:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "clientScript", "<script     language=JavaScript>get_latest_messages("+id+");</script>");
```

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) 
instead of json.length use data.length

Comment: You;re selecting the entire table using _tr = $('#tableMessage');_, but then you're appending TD elements directly to the table body. try appending them to a TR first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just changed it and tested it. Still wont work thu :(

Comment: Also see https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/javascript-dom, last paragraph.

Comment: use devtools in chrome/firefox/IE and put a breakpoint on the `var tr` line, if it gets hit then examine the data variable, if it doesn't get hit then the function isn't getting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is bad design to handle postback methods directly in request object. We all know this is how jQuery documents the implementation but it is an antipattern. It works, but is hard to read. Instead construct methods that will handle your postback data, in this case `handleJson`

You had also forgotten to actually add the TR element that is necessary for the TD's. It is also more efficient to select the table outside of the loop.

```
function get_latest_messages(id) {
    // Handle your incomming data from the api
    function handleJson(data) {
        // the data parameter is supposed to be your json
        var table = $('#tableMessage');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            table.append("<tr>" +
                "<td>" + data[i].fname + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + data[i].content + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + data[i].subject + "</td>" +
                "</tr>");
        }
    }

    // Call
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:xxxxx/api/value/' + id, handleJson);
}
```

Hej föresten och lycka till!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It still wont show any information in the table :(. Tackar!

Comment: My bad, I've had forgot to add JQuery... :D. Now it works, thank you!